# Celery: What is the best way to stagger job execution by a few minutes?

Tags: python, celery

I'm running Celery within a Flask application which accepts one-off jobs scheduled for execution at a future point in time. Suppose if multiple jobs were to be requested (by different people) scheduled for the same time, say 8pm, what is the best way to stagger the start time like 5 minutes apart instead of kicking off all the jobs at once and end up overloading the system?